# CSS Bootstrap Dropdown Menu

Tags: css

I'm using Bootstrap for my website. I want to create a menu dropdown. I have successfully created a dropdown menu, but when I add more items to the dropdown menu, they just overlap.

Here is my HTML

```
                     <li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >
                              Education<span class="caret"></span>
                          </a>
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-item">
                              <a href="signout.php">Biology </a>
                          </ul>
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-item">
                              <a href="signout.php">World History </a>
                          </ul>
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-item">
                              <a href="signout.php">English </a>
                          </ul>
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-item">
                              <a href="signout.php">Spanish </a>
                          </ul>
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-item">
                              <a href="signout.php">Psychology </a>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
```

and CSS

```
                            <style>
                        .dropdown-menu {
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 100%;
                            left: 5px;
                            margin: 8px 22px 8px 22px;
                            z-index: 1000;
                            display: none;
                            float: left;
                            min-width: 160px;
                            /*padding: 5px 0;*/
                            padding-left: 10px;
                            margin: 2px 0 0;
                            font-size: 14px;
                            text-align: right;
                            color:white;
                            list-style: none;
                            background-color: #fff; /* here */
                            -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
                            background-clip: padding-box;
                            border: 0px solid #ccc;
                            border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
                            border-radius: 0px;
                            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
                            box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
                        }
                        .nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:focus, .nav .open>a:hover {
                            background-color: transparent;
                        }
                        .dropdown-menu-item{
                            color:white;
                            background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
                        }

                        </style>
```

These are both in the HTML, so the CSS is not influenced by any other css outside of the HTML.

[currently working dropdown, but it over laps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMYzd.png)
I think i'm missing a section of CSS, something like= display:block;

I have spent a few days playing around with everything, and this code is the closest I have gotten. If there is not enough information here, please let me know and I will give more detail and evidence within a day.

Thank you so much for your time, even if you can't help. I really appreciate it.

You can view the entire project at Lukebone.com

Comment: Each of your `.dropdown-menu-item` elements are also `.dropdown-menu`. There should be only one `.dropdown-menu`, that contains all of the `.dropdown-menu-item` elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misplaced css classes

There should be only one .dropdown-menu, that contains all of the .dropdown-menu-item elements Bootstrap Menu Ex. belowe

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Education <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Biology</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">World History </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">English</a></li>                  
            <li><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Psychology</a></li>                  
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The drop down displays normally. Now all I have to do is to correctly color the CSS for it so it fits with my theme.

Comment: I really appreciate it.